# how to insert in retrieve data using <pre> in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am in that situation where i have to take input from user in  and show result in that pattern as use type in my website, along with that when user input some code like #1, #2, #3 (there codes is pre-defined to user before inserting) and that code will change into images(images are stores in files and should be called from database) can anyone help me out..... (PHP)
that code (ie #1 #2) will be inserted along with come content by users

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is completely impossible to understand.  I haven't the slightest idea what "take input from user in and show result in that pattern as use type in my website" means.

Comment: <?php $posts=$row_post['post'];
            $lst_rp = explode(' ', $posts);
                                                 foreach($lst_rp as $rp_id)
             {
                                                  $query = "SELECT * FROM smiely WHERE code='$rp_id'"; 
                                                  $result1 = mysql_query($query);  
                                                  $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);
               if($row1)
       {
 echo "<img src='smile/".$row1['img']."'>";
  }
 else{
            echo $rp_id;  
 }
 }
?>

Comment: m using this code